# How to make resource in Serverless Framework reusable?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I am trying to set up my serverless.yml file with only an API Gateway, and there are several resources that I need to reuse throughout the file, and I'd like to not copy and paste the same lines of code per resource like 100 times.

For example, I want to reuse `TestId` resource below and dynamically pass in the `Ref` under `ParentId` so I can reuse the resource for multiple parent resources. How can I do that?

```
TestResource:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
  Properties:
    ParentId:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - TestApi
        - RootResourceId
    PathPart: test
    RestApiId:
      Ref: TestApi
TestId:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
  Properties:
    ParentId:
      Ref: TestResource
    PathPart: '{id}'
    RestApiId:
      Ref: TestApi
```

Ideally I would want the resuable TestId resource in a separate file and then reference it, and also pass in the dynamic value that I want to insert in. Something like:

```
TestId: ${file(testid.yml):TestId} somehow override the TestId.Properties.ParentId.Ref: <somevalue>
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using NodeJs (if not maybe something like this exists in your programming language), I think you should take a look at this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamlinc

It allow to compose YAML files using $include tag.

Hope this helps you.